# Filling irregular polygon with given number of rectangle

Tags: python, polygon, area

I have an irregular shape polygon in which I want to fit 'n' number of rectangle with known area of all the rectangle. The area of rectangle are not same. The other constraints is that sum of area of all the n rectangle is equal to the area of irregular polygon. How to do it in python and what should be the approach?